# Android capture "down button" event or keyboard hide event

Tags: android, nativescript

I need to handle the keyboard dismiss event, I found this:
http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=261, but it handles the `activityBackPressedEvent`, but on Android when the keyboard is opened, the `backpressedevent` is not recognized, it should be a `downpressed` or something like that.

Does someone knows how to capture this event (or the "keyboard hide" event)?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can listen keyboard show/hide events by overriding onConfigurationChanged method of activity.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, but i can not make it works: i have var applicationModule = require("application");
var AndroidApplication = applicationModule.android;
var activity = AndroidApplication.foregroundActivity;

exports.loaded = function (args) {

   if (applicationModule.android) {
       applicationModule.android.on(applicationModule.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, backEvent);
       activity.android.on(activity.onConfigurationChanged, configchange);
    }

Comment: Configuration changed events aren't sent for soft keyboard hiding/showing.  Its sent for physical slider keyboards.

Comment: @GabeSechan For directly listening keyboard events it's true, but you can capture keyboard show/hide events by "screenSize" natively.

Comment: @C.Soylu no you really can't. You can try, and get it really wrong if they use picture in picture, or split apps, or another half dozen features. That's a hack that never really worked and shouldn't be used